# Restricting Access to Data Based on User Profile using Django Filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am using Django 1.11 and Django Registration Redux 1.5 and I am relatively new to programming.

I am creating an application that should display data based on a the organization of the user logged in.

I have created the following models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
organization_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
organization_type=models.CharField(max_length=50)
organization_code=models.IntegerField()
organization_krapin=models.CharField(max_length=11)
organization_contactname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
organization_contactnumber=models.IntegerField()
tariff=models.ForeignKey("Tariff", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    )

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.organization_name)

class OrganizationUserProfile(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
organization=models.ForeignKey("Organization")

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user)   

class OrganizationOrders(models.Model):
REBATE_OPTIONS = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
    )
mobile_number=models.IntegerField()
order_status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
scored_data_id=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
order_datetime=models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
order_udatetime=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
order_rebate_status=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=REBATE_OPTIONS, default='N')
organization=models.ForeignKey("Organization")

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.mobile_number)
```

And here is my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrganizationOrders001, OrganizationUserProfile

def orders(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:

    context = {
        'organization_orders': OrganizationOrders.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)
else:
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

I want to filter the OrganizationOrders based on the Organization of the user profile as registered in OrganizationUserProfile.

I will then display only the OrganizationOrders where the organization field matches the organization field of the user currently logged in.

I will appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This filter on the query should do what you want

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrganizationOrders, OrganizationUserProfile

def orders(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = {
            'organization_orders': OrganizationOrders.objects.filter(organization__organizationuserprofile__user=request.user.pk),
        }
        return render(request, 'orders.html', context)
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

Comment: Thank you for this however I am getting the following error: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Cannot query "dennis1": Must be "Organization" instance.  dennis1 is the username of the logged in user. The query needs to be of the organization that dennis1 belongs to.

Comment: @mdennism I've edited the query I think you might need to use the pk